# Pulumi automation backend

Tags: automation, pulumi, pulumi-python

I am a newbie in pulumi.  I am having an issue. When I do pulumi login in GCP backend It appears an error:

> stderr: error: getting secrets manager: passphrase must be set with
> PULUMI_CONFIG_PASSPHRASE or PULUMI_CONFIG_PASSPHRASE_FILE environment
> variables

When I do pulumi logout the deployment works - pulumi api automation. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Tried to set `pulumi_config_passphrase`.

Answer (score 1):

When using the self-managed backends for Pulumi, you need to provide a pass phrase to encrypt secret values.

This can be done by setting a global environment variable which will depend on the operating system you're using. In Unix like environments (eg MacOs or Linux) you can do:

```
export PULUMI_CONFIG_PASSPHRASE=<a password you can remember>
```

In Windows on Powershell this can be done using:

```
$env:PULUMI_CONFIG_PASSPHRASE=<a password you can remember>
```

If you don't wish to use a passphrase, you can leverage the Pulumi service as your state store, *or* configure a cloud secrets provider.

This is done when initializing your stack, more information on that can be found [here](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/secrets/#configuring-secrets-encryption)

Comment: doens t work. tried it already